# Ad Server Frequency Capping

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

Frequency Capping: It is a term in advertising that means restricting (capping) the number of times (frequency) a specific visitor to a website is shown a particular advertisement. This restriction is applied to all websites that serve ads from the same advertising network.

What does the last line means here? I am not able to understand. And whats "Same Advertising Network"

Comment: Did this answer your question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the same advertising provider. The people who actually do the bids on the advertising space.

Examples would be Atlas, Doubleclick, Rocket Fuel, Quantcast, etc, etc.